# Document of developing data studio connector is almost out of date, how can I deploy the connector via the new editor?

Tags: google-apps-script, deployment, looker-studio

The legacy apps script editor would be no longer available by September, and not all the functionality can be mapped to the new editor including "deployment by the manifest", which is necessary for deploying the connector of data studio. Updating the document at https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/deploy is necessary and must be hurry.

Does anyone know how to deploy or get the deployment id for data studio by the new apps script editor?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while to work this out as it's not intuitive nor documented, but there does seem to be a way if your manifest is set up correctly with the "dataStudio" object.

In the new editor, click the Deploy dropdown button. Then hit 'Test deployments' in the menu that displays. In the dialog box that opens, it should show 'Application(s): Data Studio' and to the right of that a button to 'Install'. Press that button and click Done.

Now press the Deploy dropdown button again and hit 'New deployment'. Now it should automatically set the deployment type to:

Add-on
Application(s): Data Studio

Just type in a description and press the 'Deploy' button and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

In the project setting mark the following:[image]